# Python CGI won't read input

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, json, cgi

I'm trying to learn how to use Python's cgi mod. Right now I'm testing a basic AJAX request to a Python script that should return a JSON object. I'm running this off xampp's Apache server and I've set the permissions of my python script as open to everyone. **My goal is to pass a JSON object to Python, alter it, then have Python return the object so I can work with it in Javascript.**

This is my python script. I currently have my input and output JSON objects separate so I can test that both sides work (but neither works):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import json
import cgi
ip = cgi.FieldStorage()

#print to file to make sure input is getting passed
f = open("pyfile.txt", "w")
f.write("girl: " + str(ip.getvalue('girl')) + "\n")
f.write("boy: " + str(ip.getvalue('boy')) + "\n")
f.close()

#test ability to return JSON object to javascript
op = {"girl":"fille", "boy":"garcon"}
print 'Content-Type: application/json\n\n'
print (json.dumps(op))
```

I have tried two different AJAX methods to run the python script. This is the first:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "script.py",
    datatype:"json",
    data: {'girl':'ragazza','boy':'ragazzo'},
    success: function(response) {
                 alert("Success!");
                 console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
             },
    error: function(a,b,c) {
               alert("Error");
           }
});
```

After I submit this request, I get the "Success!" alert and below is what prints to my console (basically what prints is my python script). Also pyfile.txt is never created.

```
"#!/usr/bin/env python\r\nimport sys\r\nimport json\r\nimport cgi\r\nip = 
cgi.FieldStorage()\r\n\r\n#print to file to make sure input is getting 
passed\r\nf = open(\"pyfile.txt\", \"w\")\r\nf.write(\"girl: \" + 
str(ip.getvalue('girl')) + \"\\n\")\r\nf.write(\"boy: \" + 
str(ip.getvalue('boy')) + \"\\n\")\r\nf.close()\r\n\r\n#test ability to return 
JSON object to javascript\r\nop = {\"girl\":\"fille\", \"boy\":\"garcon\"}
\r\nprint 'Content-Type: application/json\\n\\n'\r\nprint (json.dumps(op))"
```

So I tried a different method because I couldn't figure out what was wrong. Here's the second AJAX method I tried:

```
$.getJSON('script.py', {'girl':'ragazza', 'boy':'ragazzo'})
    .done(function(json) {
        alert("Success!");
        console.log(json['girl']);   
    })
    .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
        alert("Error");
        var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
        console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
    });
```

To which the result is an error alert and below is what is printed to my console. The unexpected token is the first char in my python script (tested this).

```
Request Failed: parsererror, SyntaxError: Unexpected token #
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've read many tutorials and stackoverflow questions, but I'm not getting anywhere. Am I supposed to run the python script from my command prompt first (I'm working on Windows) or is that only with python servers?